# Fast way to search based on non-literal comparison

Tags: algorithm, search-engine, string-comparison, levenshtein-distance, text-analysis

Fast way to search based on non-literal comparison

I am developing a small search over rather large data sets, basically all strings. The relation between the table fields are simple enough, though the comparison mustn’t be literal. i.e. it should be able to correlate “filippo“, “philippo“, “filipo“ and so forth.

I have found a few ways it could be done, very frequently stumbling on Levinstein distance ([this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675034/string-similarity-levenshtein-distance) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588541/hamming-distance-vs-levenshtein-distance)), though I am not sure it is practical on my specific case.

In a nutshell I have two tables, a small one with “search keys“ and a more massive one in which the search should be performed. Both tables have the same fields and they both have the same "meaning". E.g.

```
KEYS_TABLE
# | NAME  | MIDNAME | SURNAME | ADDRESS         | PHONE
1 | John  | Fake    | Doe     | Sesame St.      | 333-12-32
2 | Ralph | Stue    | Michel  | Bart. Ghost St. | 778-13000
...
```

and

```
SEARCH_TABLE
#   | NAME     | MIDNAME | SURNAME | ADDRESS         | PHONE
...
532 | Jhon     | F.      | Doe     | Sesame Street   | 3331232
...
999 | Richard  | Dalas   | Doe     | Sesame St.      | 333-12-32
```

All I want to do is os obtain some sort of metric, or rank for each given record on `KEYS_TABLE`, report all records from `SEARCH_TABLE` above a certain relevance (defined either by the metric or simply some "KNN" like method).

I say that Levinstein distance might not be practical because it would require to calculate for every field in every row in `KEYS_TABLE` x `SEARCH_TABLE`. Considering that `SEARCH_TABLE` has about 400 million records and `KEYS_TABLE` varies from 100k to 1mil, the resulting number is way too large.

I was hoping there was some way I could previously enrich both tables, or some simpler (cheaper) way to perform the search.

Worth mentioning that I am allowed to transform the data at will. e.g. normalise `St.` to `st`, `Street` to `st`, remove special chars and so on.

What would be my options?

Answer (score 0):

One approach (heuristic!) I can think about is:

In addition to the original fields in the table, for each field also store its *normalized form* obtained by some [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) algorithm. If you are using java, lucene's [`EnglishAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_1_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.html) might help you with this step.

Do an *exact comparison* using the standard methods to find for each entry in `table1` a list of candidates. An entry `e2` in `table2` will be a candidate to entry `e1` in `table1` if they have some common field where the normalized form matches the regular form. That can be done efficiently using some data structure that allows quick string searches - there are plenty of these.

For each entry in `e1` - find the "best" candidate/s for it in the list, using the exact metric you chose (for example your suggested leneshtein distance)

You might want to do some post-processing to make sure you don't have two elements in `table1` mapped to the same element in `table2`, if that's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what misspellings are likely, you might be able to use Soundex or Metaphone for your searches.